# Target email address validiation

Tags: jakarta-mail

Before the client sends a new email, he/she specifies one or more (To) destination addresses. Is there any  way to check the validity of these emails before sending the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InternetAddress class only checks the syntax of the address. The InternetAddress class is not able to determine whether the address actually exists as a legal address. It is not even possible to verify the host name if the application is running behind a firewall or isn't currently connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Define "validity".

This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr) might help.